# bootstrap table: how do i set maximum height and make nested content align horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a bootstrap table which contains nested content as shown below

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>hello</td>
            <td>
               <tr><td>0</td></tr>
               <tr><td>1</td></tr>
               <tr><td>2</td></tr>
               <tr><td>3</td></tr>
               <tr><td>4</td></tr>
               <tr><td>5</td></tr>
               <tr><td>6</td></tr>
               <tr><td>7</td></tr>
               <tr><td>8</td></tr>
               <tr><td>9</td></tr>
               <tr><td>10</td></tr>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Those nested contents are displayed vertically. I need a way to detect the height of `<td>`. Let's say 50px, once it exceeds the limit, `<tr>` inside `<td>` will align horizontally.
To note that the table is generated through a recursive function, the idea of it is to construct a tree table. But saving space is my priority.

Answer (score 1):

You should use another tag like `div` rather than `tr`. `tr` always decide to have a new line.
If you are using bootstrap, let you use `class="row"` for outer td and `class="col-sm-2/3//...n"` for inner `div` or other element. so that it could align horizontally.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But how do i detect the hight of cell and then make horizontal align.I don't want to make all elements align horizontally. I am thinking if there is a way using css to auto adjust height of cell and elements inside it will align correspondly. Hopefully i am not dreaming:)